# Android LinearLayout's children custom rendering animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, objectanimator, layouttransition

Here's the situation:

I have a `LinearLayout` containing vertically n `CardView`.

I want to customise the way it's rendered by adding animation on cards.

When the layout is **rendered** (maybe in *onResume()*) i want each card to slide from the bottom to the position the card should have taken if not animated, like in the illustration above: [image]
The yellow arrow represent the `LinearLayout`'s *paddingTop* and the purple arrow represents the `CardView`'s *marginBottom*.

I don't know how to achieve this because i can't get the final position, that's why i came here to ask you if someone has already done this or similar.

I tried to use `LayoutTransition` with `ObjectAnimator` added to the `LinearLayout` that animate children when added/removed, but i have to pass a view (the child, that i'm not suppose to know at this time) in `ObjectAnimator`'s constructor..

I also tried this:

```
[...]
int deviceHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
[...]
@override
public onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  card.animate().y(position)
      .withStartAction(new Runnable(){
        @Override
          public void run(){
            card.setY(deviceHeight);
          }
        });
```

but i can't get the value of *position* (i always get 0) or if i change it to *.y(-deviceHeight)* the card is rendered at his position **then** moved to bottom before it slides to the top of `LinearLayout` **but** the *paddingTop* is not even considered..

EDIT:
To sum up, i want to make something similar to what happens when *android:animateLayoutChanges="true"* is set and you remove the first child: the other children just slide up to fill the place remained empty (except that i want to add some delay between each child animation)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i made a little trick to achieve this:

Assuming the `LinearLayout` is called *cardsContainer*, i did this:

```
LayoutTransition lt = cardsContainer.getLayoutTransition();
lt.setStagger(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, 200);
```

This piece of code adds 200ms to every animation of each child that moves because of of them has been removed, so i had an empty `View` (*ghostcard*) on top that **match_parent** then i do this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus) {
        cardsContainer.removeView(findViewById(R.id.ghostcard));
    } else {
        cardsContainer.addView(ghostCard, 0);
    }
}
```